# What could cause errors in the positions output by multipartite_layout in NetworkX?

Tags: networkx

I wrote a script that draws directed graphs with a multipartite layout. Each node stores information about which layer it should be plotted in. It looks like the multipartite layout is either not using this information or has some kind of bug. For example,

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('a',layer=2)
G.add_node('b',layer=3)
G.add_node('c',layer=1)
G.add_node('d',layer=2)
G.add_node('e',layer=4)
nx.multipartite_layout(G,align='horizontal',subset_key='layer')
```

outputs

```
{'d': array([-0.27777778, -0.66666667]),
 'a': array([ 0.27777778, -0.66666667]),
 'b': array([ 0.        , -0.11111111]),
 'c': array([0.        , 0.44444444]),
 'e': array([0., 1.])}
```

However, the expected outcome is to have a layout where vertex c is plotted in a first layer, then a and d, then b, and lastly e.

For what it's worth, I had this same issue in an older computer and a fresh reinstall of Anaconda solved the problem. This time I'm working on a completely new computer (running on Windows 11) and uninstalling/reinstalling is not helping.